# No Team Found in Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, ipa

I have recently updated my mac and this weird issue has come up at the time of creating archive.

I am getting "No team found in archive" error, after clicking "Distribute App" button. Here are the screen shots
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many things. I would like to share what worked for me.

1. Goto Library/Developer/XCode and delete "DerivedData" folder.
2. Clean Build Folder : in xcode "Product" menu -> "Clean Build Folder" or press "Command+shift+K".
3. Close XCode.
4. Re-open XCode and your project.
5. Try creating new build.